# git submodule update doesn't work for in GitHub CI/CD pipeline for branched submodule

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-branch, git-submodules

When I call

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --depth 50 --remote --jobs 1
```

for a submodule with a branch named `main` this works fine when I call it from local git bash while it fails when called from a GitHub CI/CD pipeline:

```
13:27:13.378819 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify origin/main
fatal: Needed a single revision
13:27:13.381233 git.c:742               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Unable to find current ${remote_name}/${branch} revision in submodule path '\''$sm_path'\'''
13:27:13.381277 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Unable to find current ${remote_name}/${branch} revision in submodule path '\''$sm_path'\'''
13:27:13.384468 git.c:742               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Unable to find current ${remote_name}/${branch} revision in submodule path '\''$sm_path'\'''
13:27:13.384504 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Unable to find current ${remote_name}/${branch} revision in submodule path '\''$sm_path'\'''
fatal: Unable to find current origin/main revision in submodule path 'roles/trendmicro-ds-agent-branch'
```

This is my .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "roles/trendmicro-ds-agent-branch"]
    path = roles/trendmicro-ds-agent-branch
    url = ../../modules/ansible/trendmicro-ds-agent
    branch = main
```

It also works fine in the pipeline when I replace `branch = main` by `branch = master` (where master is the master branch in the submodule project) in .gitmdoules.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: The `--remote` flag to `git submodule update` means: *after running `git fetch` in the submodule, use origin/<name> to figure out which commit to check out* where <name> is the branch name in your `.gitmodules` file (it's a bit more involved than that but that's the end result here). So if they don't have a `main`, so that you don't have an `origin/main`, you'll get this error. You must use a name such that, when `origin/` is stuck on the front, you get a name that your Git set up based on the names in their (the submodule upstream) repository. If that's `master`, that's what you must use.

Comment: If the problem occurs only when on a CI system, it's possible that your clone is a single-branch clone. That would generally be the case with `--depth 50` since `--depth` *implies* `--single-branch`. So the one branch you cloned is the only `origin/<name>` name you'll get. To fix *that*, so that you get `origin/foo` if there's a `foo` branch, make your CI system *not* do a single-branch clone: add `--no-single-branch` to the submodule instructions and/or do whatever your CI system says to do to avoid single-branch clones.

Comment: Putting these two together, then, it seems likely that they have both master and main (which seems weird but some people might do that) *and* your use of `--depth` is causing you to pick up on the `master` name so that you have only `origin/master` in your submodule clone, so that only `master` will work as a name. You can either use that name *or* fix the single-branch issue.

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer. Both master and branch exist of course in my submodule's project. Simply adding ```GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: --no-single-branch --remote --jobs 1``` to my .gitlab-ci.yml unfortunately does not yet solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the [`--single-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---no-single-branch) option is *not* set when checking out the whole working copy.

Git will also apply this setting to your submodule. It will only checkout the default branch (`master` in your case). Later, when you run `git submodule update` to switch to the configured `branch = main`, it can't find it *locally* and fails.

#### GitHub Actions

As you mentioned GitHub CI/CD. If you use the [`actions/checkout` action](https://github.com/actions/checkout), it's sufficient to run with `fetch-depth: 0` to make sure it fetches *all* the branches:

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```